# Display images with WickedPDF on an RoR App

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb, wicked-pdf, generate

I actually generate PDF with WickedPDF on my app. And now I just want to include an image "logo.jpg" on the header of my PDF.

I tried lot of things, and I think my problem come from assets.

My Controller :

```
def generate_pdf
     pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
         render_to_string(
           template: 'pdf/pdf_view.pdf.erb',
           layout: 'layouts/application.pdf.erb'))
     send_data(pdf,
     filename: 'file_name.pdf',
     type: 'application/pdf',
     disposition: 'attachment')
end
```

layouts/application.pdf.erb :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body onload='number_pages'>
    <div id="content">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

pdf/pdf_view.pdf.erb :

```
<div>
    <p>Just a simple text on my pdf that is correctly displayed</p>
  <%= wicked_pdf_image_tag "images/logo.jpg", :width=>"250", :height=>"200" %>
</div>
```

And in my console :

```
Rendering pdf/pdf_view.pdf.erb within layouts/application.pdf.erb
  Rendered pdf/pdf_view.pdf.erb within layouts/application.pdf.erb (2.7ms)
[wicked_pdf]: ["/home/vincent/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20210503-14279-o2q5ol.html", "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20210503-14279-1om4oam.pdf"]
source=rack-timeout id=cfb572c3-5919-47c1-b32c-cc3bf724b9bf timeout=15000ms service=1000ms state=active
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.1ms)
Sent data file_name.pdf (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1140ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

So my question is : **Do you have an other method to display an image on a generated pdf ? Or is my method wrong ?**

Comment: which rails version you are using. I had the same issue and may be can help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the right command to display my images on the pdf is :

```
image_tag wicked_pdf_asset_base64
```